# Textura en Esfera con Open GL

Tags: c++, opengl

Estoy tratando de poner una textura en un objeto quadric de glut en c++ pero por alguna razón me esta poniendo la textura en el fondo, soy nuevo con glut, si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

```
void drawScene(void){

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
    GLUquadric *quad;
    quad = gluNewQuadric();
    gluLookAt(x0,y,z0,xref,yref,zref,Vx,Vy,Vz);
    //glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glTranslatef(Xvalue, Yvalue, 0);
    GLint texture = LoadTexture("txVenus.bmp");
    gluQuadricTexture(quad, GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gluSphere(quad, 24, 30, 30);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podría ser que la textura se estuviese aplicando pero al no haber iluminación se ve la esfera negra? ¿Qué shader has usado? (no creo que necesites cargar la textura a cada pase de `drawScene`).

Comment: Es que la textura se aplico en el fondo y no sobre la esfera y no se porque.
Tampoco tiene iluminación y solo quiero que funcione por eso esta en drawScene

Comment: Perdona, me refería a que la textura se aplicara a todo. Las tarjetas gráficas son máquinas de estados y cuando en el estado tienen una textura, todas las llamadas a render posteriores utilizan dicha textura.

Comment: Has cambiado el orden en el que haces glBindTexture a justo después de gluSphere?

Comment: pues no estoy muy seguro pero tal vez tenga que ver con que estas habilitando una textura en 2D y no en 3D como deberia ser, para la gluSphere

Answer (score 3):

En OpenGL no se puede aplicar una textura al fondo. Para conseguirlo debes renderizar un polígono con un una textura.

Mi experiencia me dice que sucede lo siguiente:

Por muy extraño que te parezca la textura la está aplicando a la esfera. Y si alejas la esfera la verás correctamente. En OpenGL la matriz de proyección debe definir una distancia mínima a partir de la que es visible y una distancia máxima. Tu esfera está tan cerca de la cámara (el origen 0,0,0) que hay un parte que no es visible, por lo que ves el fondo de color negro. Dando la sensación que la esfera es negra, pero realmente es el hueco que deja la parte no visible.

Otra cosa que no deberías hacer es invocar a gluNewQuadric y LoadTexture en cada renderizado. Es como realizar reservas de memoria en la tarjeta gráfica y no liberarlas.

La carga de textura:

> GLint texture = LoadTexture("txVenus.bmp");

puedes hacerla en el main después de haber realizado el glutCreateWindow.